# Alter Postgres Tablespace

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces

I can't seem to create a table in a particular tablespace.  For instance, when I do:

```
CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (rc_id integer NOT NULL) TABLESPACE my_space;
```

and then I do:

```
select * from pg_tables where schemaname ='myschema' limit 10;
```

...the tablespace is blank.  The tablespace shows up in PgAdmin as pg_default.  What do I need to change to create the non-default tablespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, "tablespace" field of [pg_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-tables.html) says "Name of tablespace containing table (null if default for database)". To get an exact tablespace name for a table or a table list you should first get the default tablespace for particular database. The query below lists all tables in schema myschema

```
WITH tbl_spc AS (
  --Get default tablespace for the database
  SELECT ts.spcname AS spcname
    FROM pg_tablespace ts 
    JOIN pg_database db ON db.dattablespace = ts.oid
    WHERE db.datname = current_database()
)
SELECT
  t.schemaname,
  t.tablename,
  --if null then get default tablespace
  COALESCE(t.tablespace, ts.spcname) AS tablespace
FROM pg_tables t, tbl_spc ts
WHERE
  t.schemaname = 'myschema'
```